# Confusion about Generating Function of Restricted Partitions

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I ran into some confusion answering [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/954021/counting-problem-generating-function-using-partitions-of-odd-numbers-and-permut).

The OP asked for the number of partitions of an integer into odd numbers greater than $1$, with the additional constraint that there are two different choices (or colors) for each integer (it might be that the OP asked for compositions, but even if, I would like to treat *partitions* now). Eg we have four possibilities to partition $8$, namely $5_{red}+3_{red}$, $5_{red} + 3_{blue}$, $5_{blue}+3_{red}$ and $5_{blue} + 3_{blue}$.

Looking into the standard reference (Analytic Combinatorics), I found that partitions may be defined via the *multiset construction* (page 29ff). There, one first takes a combinatorial class $\mathcal B$ and its generating function $B(z)$ and sets $\mathrm{MSET}(\mathcal B) = \prod_{n \ge 1} (1-z^n)^{-B_n}$.
We have $B(z) = \sum_{n \ge 1} 2 \cdot z^{ 2n+1} $ (there are two possibilities for each odd number greater $1$), and so the generating function we are looking for is
$$
 P_1(z) = \prod_{n \ge 1} (1-z^{2n+1})^{-2}.
$$
Yet this function produces wrong coefficients (already the coefficient of $z^6$ is $3$, which is clearly wrong). A different function which I derived in an earlier attempt,
$$
 P_2(z) = \prod_{n \ge 1} (1-2z^{2n+1})^{-1},
$$
produces the right coefficients. So I guess $P_2(z)$ must be the right generating function, yet I don't clearly understand why. Also I don't know what exactly $P_1(z)$ counts. Did I misunderstand the multiset construction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Note:** I've posted a detailed answer to the [question of the OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/954021) which also clarifies your question.

**First of all:** You *did not misunderstand the multiset construction* and the function $P_1(z)$ is *actually the generating function for the partitions* of two-colored, odd integers $>1$.

> *Two hints:*
>
> - Observe that the number of *partitions* of two-colored,odd integers $> 1$ of $6$ is $3$, namely
>     $$6=3_b+3_b=3_b+3_r=3_r+3_r$$
>     while the number of *compositions* of $6$ is $4$
>     $$6=3_b+3_b=3_b+3_r=3_r+3_b=3_r+3_r$$
> - The function $P_2(z)$ is regrettably neither the generating function for compositions nor for partitions.
>
> The number of partitions with two-colored, odd integers $> 1$ of $10$ is $7$,
>   the number of compositions of $10$ is $12$,
>   while $[z^{10}]P_2(z)=8$.

**Note:** Last, but not least I fully agree with you: Flajolets book is an outstanding classic. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much. I miscounted the number of partitions for $n=6$.

Comment: @john_leo: You're welcome! It was interesting and a pleasure for me to clarify these things. Especially at the beginning your $P_2(z)$ seemed to be a plausible candidate! :-)