# counting with constraints

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I have to count all the chains of $1$ and $2$ of length $n$ where every $1$ is followed by at list $d$ $2$'s.

I started by the simpler case where $d=1$ and the number of $1$'s is maximum (i.e it can not be another 1 because it will be less than $d$ from the next or the previous one). I realized in this case the maximum number of 1's is $\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$ and in general it is $\lfloor\frac{n}{d+1}\rfloor$.

Also when the $n=(d+1)q+1$ the number of chains with maximum number of $1$'s is $1$ for general $n$ and $d$.

But I'm stuck in other cases... Naturally, I can count all the chains with $k$ ones, but how I discard those which don't satisfy the restriction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can some 2's precede the first 1?

Comment: are "chains" (linear) strings or (circular) necklaces ?

Comment: @user yes, and it can be more than d 2's between each one. But it MUST be at least d.

Comment: @G_Cab Sorry for the non clear post. Here chains are supposed to be strings.

Comment: Please answer only the question "Can some 2's precede the **first** 1?". If so, is there any restriction on the number of 2's **preceding** the **first** 1?

Comment: @user yes it can. And there is not restrictions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing "chain" means string, i.e. word, then we are dealing with binary words of  lenght $n$, where

*a) all the ones (including the last) shall be followd by at least $d$ two's*

In this case we can figure out that each one be followed by a "bumper" string of $d$ two's.
Assuming that the word contains $q$ ones, that is the same as deleting $qd$ two's from the total length 
and distributing the $q$ ones into $n-qd$ places.
That can be done in 
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
N\left( {n,d,q} \right) = \left( \matrix{
  n - qd \cr 
  q \cr}  \right) = \left( \matrix{
  n - qd \cr 
  n - q\left( {d + 1} \right) \cr}  \right)
} \tag{a.1} $$
where the second writing shall be preferred, because it ensures that $N(n,d,q)$ be null when
$n<q(d+1)$, taking for the binomial the [definition through falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Generalization_and_connection_to_the_binomial_series).

Then the answer to your question is 
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
N\left( {n,d} \right) = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,q\,\left( { \le \left\lfloor {n/\left( {d + 1} \right)} \right\rfloor \, \le \,n} \right)\;} {\left( \matrix{
  n - qd \cr 
  n - q\left( {d + 1} \right) \cr}  \right)} \quad \left| {\;0 \le n,d \in Z} \right.
} \tag{a.2} $$
where the bounds for $q$ can be generally extended to $0,\,cdots,\, n$, since the actual bounds are intrinsic to the binomial.

In the hypothesis (*user*'s comment) that the first one is not preceded by any two, then the position of the first $d+1$ block of letters would be fixed, and the number of ways of obtaining such a configuration would just become   $N(n-(d+1),\, d,\, q-1)$.

*b) all the ones (except the last) shall be followed by at least $d$ two's, i.e. the ones are separated by at least $d$ two's.*

In this alternative interpretation, it also means that each $1$ occupies $d+1$ consecutive places, except the last, which 
can be followed by whichever number of $2$'s.
Let's place the last one at position $j$, with $1 \le j \le n$.
Then we are left with $j-1$ positions where to place $q-1$ ones occupying $d+1$ places.
That is the same as telling that we are disposing $q-1$ identical objects into a total of $j-1-(q-1)d$ cells.

So the total number of ways of arranging $q$ ones will be
$$
\eqalign{
  & N\left( {n,d,q} \right) = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,j\, \le \,n} {\left( \matrix{
  j - 1 - \left( {q - 1} \right)d \cr 
  q - 1 \cr}  \right)}  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n - 1} {\left( \matrix{
  k - \left( {q - 1} \right)d \cr 
  k - \left( {q - 1} \right)\left( {d + 1} \right) \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
    &  = \sum\limits_{(0\, \le) \,k\, (\le \,n - 1)} {\left( \matrix{
  n - 1 - k \cr 
  n - 1 - k \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  k - \left( {q - 1} \right)d \cr 
  k - \left( {q - 1} \right)\left( {d + 1} \right) \cr}  \right)}  = \left( \matrix{
  n - \left( {q - 1} \right)d \cr 
  n - 1 - \left( {q - 1} \right)\left( {d + 1} \right) \cr}  \right) \cr} 
$$
where the steps are:
 -1) change index range
 -2) bring index range inside the sum, as an additional binomial, so as to let $k$ free of bounds
 -3) apply the "double convolution" formula
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_k {\left( \matrix{
  a - k \cr 
  m - k \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  b + k \cr 
  n + k \cr}  \right)}  = \sum\limits_k {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,m - k} \left( \matrix{
  m - a - 1 \cr 
  m - k \cr}  \right)\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,n + k} \left( \matrix{
  n - b - 1 \cr 
  n + k \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,m + n} \left( \matrix{
  m + n - a - b - 2 \cr 
  n + m \cr}  \right) = \left( \matrix{
  a + b + 1 \cr 
  n + m \cr}  \right) \cr} 
$$

Now let's check the validity of the above for low values of $q,\, n,\, d$ :
 - $0$ ones can be placed in $1$ way, checks with ${{n+d} \choose {n+d}}$;
 - $1$ one can be placed in $n$ ways, checks with ${{n} \choose {n-1}}$;
 - $2$ ones can be placed in ${{n-d} \choose {2}}$, checks with ${{n-d} \choose {n-2-d}}$;
 - for $n=q=0$ we get $1$, the empty string;
 - for $d=0$ we get ${{n} \choose {n-q}}$ as it shall be.

Thus we can conclude that 
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
N\left( {n,d,q} \right) = \left( \matrix{
  n - \left( {q - 1} \right)d \cr 
  n - 1 - \left( {q - 1} \right)\left( {d + 1} \right) \cr}  \right)\quad \left| {\;0 \le n,q,d \in \mathbb Z} \right.
} \tag{b.1} $$
and of course the answer to your question will be the sum of $N(n,d,q)$ over $q$
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
N\left( {n,d} \right) = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,q\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {\left( \matrix{
  n - \left( {q - 1} \right)d \cr 
  n - 1 - \left( {q - 1} \right)\left( {d + 1} \right) \cr}  \right)} \quad \left| {\;0 \le n,d \in \mathbb Z} \right.
} \tag{b.2} $$
where the bounds for $q$ can be generally extended to $0,\,\cdots,\, n$, since the actual ones are intrinsic to the binomial.

**Example**

$n=5,\; d=2,\; q=2 \quad \Rightarrow \quad N(n,d,q)=3$
$$(1,\, 0,\, 0,\, 1,\, 0) ,\; (1,\, 0,\, 0,\, 0,\, 1) ,\; (0,\, 1,\, 0,\, 0,\, 1) $$

$n=6,\; d=2,\; q=2 \quad \Rightarrow \quad N(n,d,q)=6$
$$(1,\, 0,\, 0,\, 1,\, 0,\, 0) ,\; (1,\, 0,\, 0,\, 0,\, 1,\, 0) ,\; (1,\, 0,\, 0,\, 0,\, 0,\, 1) ,\; (0,\, 1,\, 0,\, 0,\, 1,\, 0) ,\; (0,\, 1,\, 0,\, 0,\, 0,\, 1) ,\; (0,\, 0,\, 1,\, 0,\, 0,\, 1) $$

Comment: Besides the one deviation everything else looks sound. (+1) for the nice elaboration.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer:  Thanks, Markus, and same for your approach through ogf.  So, finally  I recasted my answer according to two possible interpretations (since the last was already worked out, by mistake ..).

Comment: Hi! @GCab thanks for your answers! (both of them turn useful for me!) can you explain me please the last step when you are computing $N(n,d,q)$ at b)? I tried to prove it by induction on n but I came to a deadend...

Comment: @ARo: I explained how to construct $N(n,d,q)$ from the starting of para. b). Please tell me which of those steps are not clear to you.

Comment: the very last equality where you said $$\sum_{0\leq k\leq n-1}\binom{n-1-k}{n-1-k}\binom{k-(q-1)d}{k-(q-1)(d+1)} =\binom{n-(q-1)d}{n-1-(q-1)(d+1)}$$. Now I reallized it looks similar to the Vandermonde identity which is 
$$
\sum_{j=0}^H \binom{m}{j}\binom{N-m}{H-j}=\binom{N}{H}
$$
but I did't find make it fit, I get this
$$
\sum_{0\leq n-1-k\leq n-1-(q-1)(d+1)}\binom{n-k}{n-1-k}\binom{k-(q-1)d}{k-(q-1)(d+1)} =\binom{n-(q-1)d}{n-1-(q-1)(d+1)}
$$

Comment: @ARo: added explanation, let me know if you need other details

Comment: @GCab: Thanks, I didn't know that formula! There is a paper where I can read about it?

Answer (score 3):

We interprete the problem as follows: Given is the alphabet $V=\{1,2\}$. Find the number of strings consisting of characters of $V$ of length $n\geq 0$ so that each occurrence of $1$ is followed by *at least* $d$ characters $2$. We do so by encoding the problem using generating functions.

> Each of the admissible strings starts with zero or more $2$'s. This can be encoded as
>   \begin{align*}
> 1+z+z^2+\cdots=\frac{1}{1-z}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>
> Each so created string can be followed by zero or more $1$'s, whereby each occurrence of $1$ is replaced by $1$ followed by at least $d$ $2$'s. This can be encoded as
>   \begin{align*}
> 1+z(z^d+z^{d+1}+\cdots)+z^2(z^d+z^{d+1}+\cdots)^2+\cdots&=\frac{1}{1-z\left(z^d+z^{d+1}\cdots\right)}\\
> &=\frac{1}{1-\frac{z^{d+1}}{1-z}}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

Multiplying (1) and (2) together we get a generating function $A(z)$ where $[z^n]$, i.e. the coefficient of $z^n$, contains the number of admissible strings of length $n$.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[z^n]A(z)}&=[z^n]\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{z^{d+1}}{1-z}}\right)=[z^n]\frac{1}{1-z(1+z^d)}\\
> &=[z^n]\sum_{j=0}^\infty z^j(1+z^d)^j\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^n [z^{n-j}](1+z^d)^j\tag{4}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^n [z^j](1+z^d)^{n-j}\tag{5}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^n[z^j]\sum_{k=0}^{n-j}\binom{n-j}{k}z^{dk}\tag{6}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{d}\right\rfloor}[z^{dj}]\sum_{k=0}^{n-dj}\binom{n-dj}{k}z^{dk}\tag{7}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{d}\right\rfloor}\binom{n-dj}{j}}\tag{8}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (3) we apply the geometric series expansion.
- In (4) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and apply the rule $[z^{p-q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^qA(z)$. We also set the upper limit of the series to $n$ since the exponent of $z$ is non-negative.
- In (5) we change the order of summation $j\to n-j$.
- In (6) we apply the binomial theorem.
- In (7) we observe that we need only multiples of $d$ as exponent.
- In (8) we select the coefficient accordingly.

Comment: I get a slight different result: can you check? thanks

Comment: @GCab: I do not see in OP's problem that the last $1$ could have a special role. I think *each* $1$ has to be followed by at least $d$ $2$'s. I'll check for other differences tomorrow.

Comment: Oops, that's true ! OP states that "..every 1 is followed  .." . I misunderstood that.

Comment: Hello @MarkusScheuer thanks for your answer, the calculations are so well explained! can you explain how you encode a string by a series - or say me where I can read about it :) -

Comment: @ARo: You're welcome. You might find in this *[MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1025978/counting-binary-strings-that-have-atmost-k-consecutive-0s/1044196#1044196)* a more detailed explanation of the mapping between strings and generating functions. The perfect starter is Wilf's *Generatingfunctionology*. See *[this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/742083/book-on-combinatorial-identities/748850#748850)* containing refs.

Comment: I will check it out! thanks again!