# Random walk on natural number

Tags: probability, random-walk

**Problem:**

You are standing at the position $0$ on the line of natural numbers $0, 1, 2, ..., n$. From this position you go to $1$ with probability $1$,
but from any other position $i$ you go to $i+1$ with probability $p$ and respectively to $i-1$ with probability $1-p$. What is the expected number of steps to go from 0 to n?

Just to be clear. There is no way you can end up on the negative number. And once you reach $n$ the game stops, so you can not end up on any number bigger than $n$.

---

Here is my approach to tackle this problem:

Let $N_i$ is the expected number of steps to reach $n$ from a position $i$.
It is obvious that $N_n = 0$. Also $N_0 = 1 + N_1$. And if we select any number $i$ from $1$ to $n-1$, then $N_i = (1 - p) \cdot N_{i-1} + p \cdot N_{i+1} = 1 + (1-p) \cdot N_{i-1} + p \cdot N_{i+1}$.

Now I am trying to simplify things having these three equations:

$$N_0 = 1 + N_1\\
N_i = 1 + (1-p) \cdot N_{i-1} + p \cdot N_{i+1}\\
N_n = 0$$

**Approach 1**

Putting $i = 1$ in equation (2) I found that $N_1 = 2/p - 1 + N_2$, which I later put in (1) to get $N_0 = 2/p + N_2$

Doing the same with $i = 2$ I got $N_2 = 1 - 2/p + 2/p^2 + N_3$ and $N_0 = 1 + 2/p^2 + N_3$.

Just one more step with $i = 3$ gives me $N_3 = N_4 + 4/p - 4/p^2 + 2/p^3 - 1$ and $N_0 = 4/p - 2/p^2 + 2/p^3 + N_4$

I was doing all this in hope of finding some relationship which would allow me to guess what will be the relationship for the last or one before last step. But I fail to see any and therefore I gave up.

**Approach 2**

I noticed that:
$N_0 - N_1 = 1$ and $N_{i-1} - N_i = 1 + (1 - p) \cdot (N_{i-2} - N_i)$

Here if I will sum the left side, I will get $N_0 - N_n = N_0$ and this gave me hope that I can get some closed form expression if I will add the right side. But when I add them up I got $n + (1 - p)(N_0 + N_1 - N_{n-1} - N_{n})$. This gave me $N_0 = \frac{n + (N_1 - N_{n-1})(1-p)}{p}$ which leads me nowhere because of $N_1$ and $N_{n-1}$.

**Approach 3** (similar to approach 2, but I expand the first element, not the second). I will not write it completely, not because I have not thought about, but because I value your time and I think that
the post is already too long.

So $N_0 - N_1 = 1$ and $N_i - N_{i+1} = -1 + p (N_i - N_{i+2})$. After the same summation idea as in approach 2 I ended up with $N_1$, $N_2$ and $N_{n-1}$ elements.

---

After this I gave up completely. Here I am not really sure that my starting idea

> Let $N_i$ is the expected number of steps to reach $n$ from a position
>   $i$.

is correct or whether the close formula for expected value exist. So how should I approach this problem?

**P.S.** I know that for $p = 0.5$ (go left and right with equal probability) the close formula exists and expected number of steps one need to take from $0$ to $n$ is $n^2$.

Comment: After "And if we select any number $i$ (where I assume you mean to restrict $0<i<n,$)" you have two expressions for $N_i$ in terms of its previous and next neighbors. I think only the second expression, with the extra added $+1,$ is correct, since one more turn has been taken. For small $n$ one gets a system of linear equations in the $N_i$ which can be solved by row reduction. I don't know if in general this gives anything nice for the desired number $N_0$ though,

Comment: It is very important to know whether your random walk allows the return to position $0$ and all the negative positions $(-1, -2, -3,...)$, or whether these positions are prohibited in your model.

Comment: @M.Wind I explained that from point $0$ you go to $1$ with 100% probability, so basically there is no way to end up on a negative number.

Comment: @Salvador Dali Yes, but on the next step there is a probability $(1-p)$ of going to position $(i-1) = 0$. And on the next turn there is the same probability of going to position $-1$. Etcetera.

Comment: @M.Wind Tried to update it. If you see any place where it looks like you can go to any negative number, please feel free to update it.

Comment: @Salvador Dali I suggest you describe the rules of your random walk as precise as possible in the top section of your post: $Problem$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes your recurrence is right, i.e.,
$$N_i = 1 + (1-p)N_{i-1} + pN_{i+1}$$
with $N_0 = 1+N_1$ and $N_n = 0$. This can be rearranged to give
$$p(N_{i+1}-N_i) - (1-p)(N_i-N_{i-1}) = -1$$
with $N_1 - N_0 = -1$ and $N_n = 0$. Setting $v_i = N_{i+1} - N_{i}$, we obtain the equations to be
$$pv_i - (1-p)v_{i-1} = -1$$
with $v_0 = -1$ and $N_n=0$. Setting $v_i = u_i + k$, we obtain
$$pu_i - (1-p)u_{i-1} + k(2p-1) = -1$$
Hence, if set $k = -\dfrac1{2p-1}$, we obtain the recurrence
$$u_i = \dfrac{1-p}p u_{i-1} \implies u_i = \left(\dfrac{1-p}p\right)^iu_0 = \left(\dfrac{1-p}p\right)^i \cdot \dfrac{2-2p}{2p-1}$$
Hence,
$$v_i = \left(\dfrac{1-p}p\right)^i \cdot \dfrac{2-2p}{2p-1} - \dfrac1{2p-1}$$
Rewriting this in terms of $N_i$, we obtain
$$N_{i+1} - N_{i} = \left(\dfrac{1-p}p\right)^i \cdot \dfrac{2-2p}{2p-1} - \dfrac1{2p-1} \text{ with }N_n = 0$$
Hence, summing from $i = {j}$ to $i=n-1$, we obtain
$$N_n - N_{j} = \sum_{i=j}^{n-1}\left(\dfrac{1-p}p\right)^i \cdot \dfrac{2-2p}{2p-1} - \sum_{i=j}^{n-1}\dfrac1{2p-1}$$
Since $N_n = 0$, we obtain
\begin{align}
N_j & = \dfrac{n-j}{2p-1} + \dfrac{2(1-p)}{1-2p} \sum_{i=j}^{n-1} \left(\dfrac{1-p}p\right)^i = \dfrac{n-j}{2p-1} + \dfrac{2(1-p)}{1-2p} \left(\dfrac{1-p}p\right)^{j}\sum_{i=0}^{n-j-1} \left(\dfrac{1-p}p\right)^i\\
& = \dfrac{n-j}{2p-1} + \dfrac{2(1-p)}{1-2p} \left(\dfrac{1-p}p\right)^{j} \cdot \dfrac{\left(\dfrac{1-p}p\right)^{n-j}-1}{\dfrac{1-p}p-1}\\
& = \dfrac{n-j}{2p-1} + \dfrac{2p(1-p)}{(1-2p)^2} \left(\dfrac{1-p}p\right)^{j} \cdot \left(\left(\dfrac{1-p}p\right)^{n-j}-1 \right)
\end{align}

Hence,
$$N_0 = \dfrac{n}{2p-1} + \dfrac{2p(1-p)}{(1-2p)^2}\left(\left(\dfrac{1-p}p\right)^n-1\right)$$

Comment: thank you for a detailed answer. One thing I find strange in it, is that the expected number of steps is undefined if the probability of stepping right and left are the same ($p=0.5$). On the other hand, this is the only case that I was able to find and my answer is that it should be $n^2$.

Comment: @SalvadorDali You would need to take $\lim_{p \to 0.5}$ of the above expression, which will give you $N^2$.

Answer (score 6):

**Note:** OPs approach is correct from my point of view. This is an alternate approach based upon the generating function of the *transitition matrix* of OPs automaton.

> Let's assume the situation with nodes $\{0,\ldots,n\}$, $n\geq 1$ and walks according to OPs rules from $0$ to $n$. We consider the $(n+1)\times(n+1)$ transition matrix $M(n+1)$ describing the *probability* to go from node $i$ to node $j$ in one step. In the following we set for convenience only $q= 1-p$. We get
> \begin{align*}
> M(n+1)=(m_{i,j})_{1\leq i,j\leq n+1}=
> \begin{cases}
> m_{1,2}=1\\
> m_{i,i+1}=p&\qquad   i=2,\ldots,n\\
> m_{i,i-1}=q&\qquad i=2,\ldots,n\\
> m_{i,j}=0&\qquad otherwise\\
> \end{cases}
> \end{align*}
> The matrix $M(n+1)$ is a *tridiagonal matrix* with zeroes in the main diagonal. We have e.g. for $n=4$ with nodes $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ the transition matrix
> \begin{align*}
> M(5)=
> \begin{pmatrix}
> \color{blue}{0}&\color{blue}{1}&\color{grey}{0}&\color{grey}{0}&\color{grey}{0}\\
> \color{blue}{q}&\color{blue}{0}&\color{blue}{p}&\color{grey}{0}&\color{grey}{0}\\
> \color{grey}{0}&\color{blue}{q}&\color{blue}{0}&\color{blue}{p}&\color{grey}{0}\\
> \color{grey}{0}&\color{grey}{0}&\color{blue}{q}&\color{blue}{0}&\color{blue}{p}\\
> \color{grey}{0}&\color{grey}{0}&\color{grey}{0}&\color{blue}{0}&\color{blue}{0}\\
> \end{pmatrix}
> \end{align*}

*Note:* It's well known, that the $k$-th power of the transition matrix contains the probabilites to go from node $i$ to node $j$ in $k$ steps. So, we are interested in the walks from $0$ to $n$ and the corresponding probability to go from $0$ to $n$ are coded in the element ${\left(M(n+1)\right)}^k_{(1,n+1)}$.

Therefore the *expected number of steps* to go from $0$ to $n$ is
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k\geq 1}k{\left(M(n+1)\right)}^k_{(1,n+1)}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

We calculate (1) by introducing the generating function $F_{n+1}(z)$ with parameter $n+1$.

\begin{align*}
F_{n+1}(z)=\sum_{k\geq 0}{\left(M(n+1)\right)}^k_{(1,n+1)}z^k\qquad\qquad n\geq 1\tag{2}
\end{align*}
and observe that the expectation value is given by
\begin{align*}
\left.{F}^{\prime}_{n+1}(z)\right|_{z=1}\tag{3}
\end{align*}

*Note:* A  great  introductory text describing this approach is *[Generatingfunctionology](http://www.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf)* by H.S. Wilf

> According to *Theorem 4.7.2* in R.P. Stanleys classic *[Enumerative Combinatorics, Vol.1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1107602629)* the generating function $F_{n+1}(z)$ in (2) is given by
> \begin{align*}
> F_{n+1}(z)=(-1)^{n}\frac{\det\left(I-zM(n+1):n+1,1\right)}{\det(I-zM(n+1))}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}
> whereby the notation $(I-zM(n+1):n+1,1)$ means, that the $(n+1)$-th row and the $1$-st column have to be skipped.

**Intermezzo:** Before we continue, we a look at two small examples. Calculating the first few numbers $N_0$ for $n=1,2,3$ based upon OPs recurrence relation give:
\begin{align*}
n=1&\qquad N_0=1\\
n=2&\qquad N_0=\frac{2}{p}\\
n=3&\qquad N_0=1+\frac{2}{p^2}\\
\end{align*}
With $p=\frac{1}{2}$ the expectation value $N_0$ is $1,4$ and $9$. These values coincide nicely with OPs information, the expectation value being $n^2$ in the symmetric case $p=q=\frac{1}{2}$.

**Example: $n=2$**

Now, let's consider in (4) the case $n=2$. Then
$$
I-zM(3)=\begin{pmatrix}\color{blue}{1}&\color{blue}{-z}&\color{grey}{0}\\\color{blue}{-qz}&\color{blue}{1}&\color{blue}{-pz}\\\color{grey}{0}&\color{blue}{0}&\color{blue}{1}\end{pmatrix}\qquad
(I-zM(3):3,1)=\begin{pmatrix}\color{blue}{-z}&\color{grey}{0}\\\color{grey}{1}&\color{blue}{-pz}\end{pmatrix}
$$
with $(I-zM(3):3,1)$ being the matrix $I-zM(3)$ with the $3$-rd row and $1$-st column skipped.

So, according to formula (4) we get
\begin{align*}
F_3(z)=\frac{\det\left(I-zM(3):3,1\right)}{\det(I-zM(3)}=\frac{pz^2}{1-qz^2}\\
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\left.{F}^{\prime}_3(z)\right|_{z=1}=\left.\frac{2pz}{(1-qz^2)^2}\right|_{z=1}=\frac{2}{p}
\end{align*}

**Example: $n=3$**

We proceed similarly with the case $n=3$.
\begin{align*}
I-zM(4)=\begin{pmatrix}\color{blue}{1}&\color{blue}{-z}&\color{grey}{0}&\color{grey}{0}\\\color{blue}{-qz}&\color{blue}{1}&\color{blue}{-pz}&\color{grey}{0}\\\color{grey}{0}&\color{blue}{-qz}&\color{blue}{1}&\color{blue}{-pz}\\\color{grey}{0}&\color{grey}{0}&\color{blue}{0}&\color{blue}{1}\end{pmatrix}\ \ 
(I-zM(4):4,1)=\begin{pmatrix}\color{blue}{-z}&\color{grey}{0}&\color{grey}{0}&\\\color{grey}{1}&\color{blue}{-pz}&\color{grey}{0}\\\color{grey}{-qz}&\color{grey}{1}&\color{blue}{-pz}\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

Again, according to formula (4) we get
\begin{align*}
F_4(z)=-\frac{\det\left(I-zM(4):4,1\right)}{\det(I-zM(4)}=\frac{p^2z^3}{1-(1-p^2)z^2}\\
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\left.{F}^{\prime}_4(z)\right|_{z=1}=\left.\frac{3p^2z^2-p^2(1-p^2)z^4}{(1-(1-p^2)z^2)^2}\right|_{z=1}=1+\frac{2}{p^2}
\end{align*}

Observe, that the results in these examples coincide with OPs $N_0$ above.

---

**[Update 2020-11-24]:** The update below is thanks to the helpful comments from @sela who pointed at some mistakes.

> **Simple expression for $F_{n+1}(z)$:**
>
> The challenge now is to find a *simple expression* for the determinants. In order to do so, we determine a *recurrence relation* for $\det(I-zM(n+1))$ and solve it. But first the simple one: The determinant of $(I-zM(n+1):n+1,1)$ is obviously
>
> \begin{align*}
> \det(I-zM(n+1):n+1,1)=(-1)^{n}p^{n-1}z^{n}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}
>
> since, when looking at the example above for $n=3$ and $n=4$ we see, that $(I-zM(n+1):n+1,1)$ has a *lower triangle shape* and so the determinant is the product of the elements of the main diagonal.

Here we take a look at $M(5)$. After expanding $M(5)$ in a first step by the last row, we expand it in the next step by its minors along the first column. We obtain
\begin{align*}
&\det(I-zM(5))=\det
\begin{pmatrix}
\color{blue}{1}&\color{blue}{-z}&0&0&0\\\color{blue}{-qz}&\color{blue}{1}&\color{blue}{-pz}&0&0\\0&\color{blue}{-qz}&\qquad=\color{blue}{1}&\color{blue}{-pz}&0\\0&0&\color{blue}{-qz}&\color{blue}{1}&\color{blue}{-pz}\\
0&0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}\\
&\qquad=\det
\begin{pmatrix}
\color{blue}{1}&\color{blue}{-z}&0&0\\\color{blue}{-qz}&\color{blue}{1}&\color{blue}{-pz}&0\\0&\color{blue}{-qz}&\color{blue}{1}&\color{blue}{-pz}\\0&0&\color{blue}{-qz}&\color{blue}{1}
\end{pmatrix}\\
&\qquad=\det
\begin{pmatrix}
\color{blue}{1}&\color{blue}{-pz}&0\\\color{blue}{-qz}&\color{blue}{1}&\color{blue}{-pz}\\0&\color{blue}{-qz}&\color{blue}{1}
\end{pmatrix}
+qz\det
\begin{pmatrix}
\color{blue}{-z}&\color{blue}{0}&0\\\color{blue}{-qz}&\color{blue}{1}&\color{blue}{-pz}\\0&\color{blue}{-qz}&\color{blue}{1}
\end{pmatrix}\\
&\qquad=\det
\begin{pmatrix}
\color{blue}{1}&\color{blue}{-pz}&0\\\color{blue}{-qz}&\color{blue}{1}&\color{blue}{-pz}\\0&\color{blue}{-qz}&\color{blue}{1}
\end{pmatrix}
-qz^2\det
\begin{pmatrix}
\color{blue}{1}&\color{blue}{-pz}\\\color{blue}{-qz}&\color{blue}{1}
\end{pmatrix}\tag{6}\\
&\qquad=\det T_3(z)-qz^2\det T_2(z)\\
\end{align*}

In the last line of the equation we introduce according to the nicely structured matrices in (6) the matrix $T_n(z)$. Observe that $T_n(z)$ is a tridiagonal matrix with $1$'s in the main diagonal and entries $-pz$ and $-qz$ above and below the diagonal.

---

> **Recurrence relation for $\det(I-zM(n+1))$ and $\det T_n(z)$:**
>
> The general formula follows the same scheme, so that following holds:
> \begin{align*}
> \det(I-zM(n+1))=\det T_{n-1}(z)-qz^2\det T_{n-2}(z)\qquad  n\geq 2\tag{7}
> \end{align*}
>
> Expanding the determinant $\det T_n(z)$ by its minors leads to the recurrence relation:
>
> \begin{align*}
> \det T_n(z)=\det T_{n-1}(z)-pqz^2\det T_{n-2}(z)\qquad n\geq3\tag{8}
> \end{align*}
> with initial conditions
> \begin{align*}
> \det T_1(z)&=\det   \begin{pmatrix}1\end{pmatrix}=1\\
> \det T_2(z)&=\det   \begin{pmatrix}1&-pz\\-qz&1\end{pmatrix}=1-pqz^2\\
> \end{align*}
>
> We can solve the recurrence relation for $T_n(z)$ by applying standard techniques which can be found in H.S. Wilf's *[Generatingfunctionology](http://www.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf)*. We  obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> \det T_n(z)=\frac{\left(1+\sqrt{1-4pqz^2}\right)^{n+1}-\left(1-\sqrt{1-4pqz^2}\right)^{n+1}}{2^{n+1}\sqrt{1-4pqz^2}}\qquad n\geq 1\tag{9}
> \end{align*}

---

> **Conclusion:** Putting all together we derive from (4) the following representation of the generating function $F_{n+1}(z)$:
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{F_{n+1}(z)}&=(-1)^{n}\frac{\det\left(I-zM(n+1):n+1,1\right)}{\det(I-zM(n+1))}\\
> &=\frac{p^{n-1}z^n}{\det T_{n-1}(z)-qz^2\det T_{n-2}(z)}\tag{$\longrightarrow\quad (5),(7)$}\\
> &=\frac{(pz)^n}{p\det T_{n-1}(z)-pqz^2\det T_{n-2}(z)}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{(pz)^n}{\det T_{n}(z)-q\det T_{n-1}(z)}}\tag{$\longrightarrow\quad (8)$}
> \end{align*}
>
> We  finally obtain  number of expected steps from $0$ to $n$ by evaluating the first derivation at $z=1$
> \begin{align*}
> \left.{F}^{\prime}_{n+1}(z)\right|_{z=1}
> \end{align*}
> where we can use the representation (9) of the determinants $\det T_n(z)$.

Comment: thank you for another approach. It is sad, that my current mathematical knowledge is not enough to understand it :-(

Comment: @SalvadorDali: You're welcome and don't worry. When scanning through my answer and you find some aspects interesting, I recommend you go through H.S. Wilf's *Generatingfunctionology*. It's funny to read and a proper way to learn a lot about this and other powerful techniques. Here's an [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/742083/book-on-combinatorial-identities/748850#748850) adressing corresponding literature. Best regards,

Comment: thank you. I actually was looking for a good introduction to generating functions, so I hope that your suggestion will help me.

Comment: Dear Markus. Your solution is beautiful but I believe there are two errors in your formula for $F_{n+1}(z)$: First, I think the (-1)^n should be deleted since it should actually appear twice. Second, in the denominator I believe it should be $\det T_{n-1}(z) - qz^2\det T_{n-2}(z)$.

Comment: @Sela: Many thanks for your nice comment and also for pointing at some mistakes. I've corrected my answer accordingly. Best regards,

Answer (score 3):

You already have the solution to the problem in the difference equation
$$N_i=1+(1-p)\cdot N_{i-1}+p\cdot N_{i+1}$$
with boundary conditions
$$N_n=0 \text{ and } N_0=1+N_1,$$
and all that remains is the technical issue of finding the solutions. You may want to look up solutions to difference equations to learn more about it, but here's a quick go at this particular problem.

First, let's rewrite it
$$D[N]_i=N_i-(1-p)\cdot N_{i-1}-p\cdot N_{i+1}=1$$
where $D$ denotes the difference operation, at first without worrying about the boundary conditions at $i=0$ and $i=n$. Note that if you have any solution to this, you can add $\Delta N_i$ to it where
$$D[\Delta N]_i=\Delta N_i-(1-p)\cdot \Delta N_{i-1}-p\cdot \Delta N_{i+1}=0$$
so the strategy is to find any solutions to the former and all solutions to the latter.

If we try $N_i=1$, this makes $D[N]_i=0$, so this would be a solution for $\Delta N_i$. If we try $N_i=i$, we get $D[N]_i=1-2p$; to get $D[N]_i=1$, we may enter $N_i=i/(1-2p)$ which works for $p\not=1/2$. If we also try out $N_i=i^2$, we find that for $p=1/2$ we may use $N_i=-i^2$ to get $D[N]_i=1$. (All this assumes I didn't make any mistakes in my calculations, but the idea should be the same.)

So now we have *one* solution to the difference equation. To get all, we need to solve $D[\Delta N]_i=0$. This type of difference equation often has solutions on the form $\Delta N_i=q^i$. We already know the one with $q=1$, and solving gives another with $q=1/p-1$.

Combining the initial solution $N_i=i/(1-2p)$ with the two solutions for $\Delta N_i$ gives the general solution for $p\not=1/2$:
$$N_i=\frac{i}{1-2p}+a+b\cdot\left(\frac{1}{p}-1\right)^i.$$
Now, plug in $N_n=0$ and $N_0=1+N_1$ and solve for $a,b$ to get the appropriate boundary conditions.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. One thing I find strange in it, is that the expected number of steps is undefined if the probability of stepping right and left are the same ($p=0.5$). On the other hand, this is the only case that I was able to find and my answer is that it should be $n^2$

Comment: @SalvadorDali: It's not undefined, it's just that it's a special case with a special solution. I just didn't write that case out. I suspect taking the limit will give the same as doing $p=1/2$ from scratch.