# Find $v_k$ the probability of absorption at $N$ if the walk starts at $S_0=k$ for $0 \leq k \leq N$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, recurrence-relations, homogeneous-equation

Supose that $(S_n)_{n\geq0}$ is a random walk on $\{0,1,2,\dots,N\}$ with up prbability of $p$ and down probability of $(p-1)$. Find $v_k$ the probability of absorption at $N$ if the walk starts at $S_0=k$ for $0 \leq k \leq N$

---

$v_k=\mathbb{P}($win$)$

$v_k=pv_{k+1}+(1-p)v_{k-1}$

and $v_0=0$ and $v_N=1$. The auxillary equation for this difference equation is

$p\lambda^2-\lambda+(1-p)=0$

$(p\lambda-(1-p))(\lambda-1)=0$

i.e. $\lambda=\frac{1-p}{p}$ or $1$. If $p=\frac{1}{2}$, then the homogeneous equation ($w_k$) is

$w_k=A+B$

I am unsure of where to go from here because $v_0=0=A+B$ and $v_N=1=A+B$, which seems to suggest that $A=B=0$, ie. $v_k=0$, which cannot be true.

I know how to do it if $p\neq(1-p)$. I am guessing that perhaps a different strategy is in order?

Comment: If $p=1/2$ you have equal roots in the auxillary equation, so the homogenous equation should be $w_k =A+Bk$.

Comment: @BobtheBuilds: You might find this *[related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1277675/random-walk-on-natural-number/1286805#1286805)* helpful