# How many different sums of parts of a vector

Tags: combinatorics

The following mathematical puzzle was given to me by a friend a while ago and I can't work out how to solve it. Does anyone have any ideas?

For a given vector $v \in \{-1,1\}^n$ we consider the following $n$ sums. $$S_j=\sum_{i=0}^j v_i - \sum_{i=j+1}^{n-1} v_i \text{ for } 0 \leq j \leq n-1.$$

For example if $v = (-1,1,1)$ then $S=(-3,-1,1).$

Now let $T_j = 1$ if $S_j>0$ and $0$ otherwise. So for our example vector $v$ we have that $T=(0,0,1)$

Considered over all $2^n$ possible vectors $v$, the question is how many different possible vectors $T$ are there?

I think if $n=2$ the answer is $3$, if $n=3$ the answer is $8$, if $n=4$ the answer is $11$, if $n=5$, the answer is $22$ and if $n=6$ the answer is $31$.

---

Posted to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/212389/how-many-different-sums-of-parts-of-a-vector where a possible answer has been given in the comments.

Comment: Interesting question. I wonder if it's conected to Erdos' discrepancy problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%B11-sequence

Comment: Maybe a reccurrence on $S_j$ is possible e.g. $S_{j + 1} = S_j \pm2$.

Comment: If you plot $S_j$ against $j$ then you get (in general) a zigzag, where each step goes up or down $2$. Now, $S_{n-1} - S_0 = 2 \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}v_i$ so, unless that sum is zero, $S_{n-1}$ and $S_0$ have opposite sign. If you split the line into three by dividing it at the first and last changes of sign (with a special case for sum is zero, sign never changes), you can show that it's only necessary to consider cases where $(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}v_i) \in \{0,1,2\}$, since any crossing set found with a larger value than those can be "simulated" with a smaller value of the same parity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $t_n$ be the number of distinct vectors $T$ of length $n$ that can be made using the above process. Here I will just provide an upper bound on $t_n$. That is $t_n \leq 2F_{n + 2}$, where $F_n$ is the $n^{th}$ Fibonnaci number. First, some definitions; then a proof.

**Definition (Compressed form):** For any vector $U$ whose elements are in $\{0, 1\}$, we can write it it's compressed form $C$ as follows: $u_0[c_1, c_2, \dots, c_m]$. Here $u_0$ is the initial term, and each $c_i$ is a non-zero natural number representing a contiguous run of $0$ or $1$. Note in particular that $m \leq n$ always holds. For example, the sequence $(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)$ would be represented as $0[1, 3, 2, 1]$.

**Proof (of upper bound)**: Well, according to the lemma below, we know that the compressed form $C$ of any vector $T$ can only have $c_i$ terms are all odd, except possibly the first and last terms. Also, no term is $0$. It is also clear that the sum $c_1 + c_2 + \dots + c_m = n$, from the definition of a compressed sequence. From [elsewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1373878/ordered-sum-of-odd-numbers), we can show that the number of odd sequences adding up to some number $n$ is $F_{n + 2}$. Now, if we relax this constraint so that the first and/or last term can be even, we get four possibilities for the first/last term: even/even, even/odd, odd/even, odd/odd. Subtracting 1 from a non-zero even number always gives us an odd number, so the above number of combinations above are $F_{n - 2}, F{n - 1}, F{n - 1}, F_{n}$. Summing these up and using the standard Fibonnaci recurrence gives $F_{n + 2}$. Now, the first term of a compressed sequence can be either $1$ or $0$, so we get $2F_{n + 2}$ for an upper bound, as required.

**Lemma:** The compressed form of any vector $T$, constructed as in the question, contains all odd numbers, except at its first and last terms. To see why this is the case, consider some intermediate term $k$ in the compressed form. This corresponds to a run $T_{i + 1}, T_{i + 2}, \dots, T_{i + k}$, with $T_{i + k + 1} = T_{i} \neq T_{i + 1}$ and $T_{i + j} = T_{i + h}$ for all $1 \leq j, h \leq k$. That is, it corresponds to $k$ a sub-sequence  of $k$ equal terms in a row, and two different terms immediately before and after the sequence, which are themselves equal. Now, suppose $k$ is even, towards a contradiction. Well, consider the $S$ vector that created the $T$ vector. Notice that for any $a$, $S_{a + 1} = S{a} \pm2$. Also note that $T_i \neq T_{i + 1}$ by definition. Now define $D_a = \frac{S_{i + a} - Si}{2}$. We show, inductively, that for odd $a$, this value is odd, and for even $a$ it is even. This is clearly true for $a = 0$. For the inductive case $a = n + 1$, we know that $S_{n + 1} = S_{n}\pm2$. So $D_{n + 1} = D_n\pm1$. So the parity of $D_n$ clearly alternates between successive terms. Now, we have assumed an even $k$. Which means $D_k$ must be even, and $D_{k + 1}$ odd. So then $S_{i + k + 1} \neq S_i$. But by the definition of the compressed form, $T_{i + k + 1} = T_i$. The only way this is possible, from the definition of $T$, is if $S_{i + k + 1} = S_{i} - 2$ and $S_i \leq 0$ or $S_{i + k + 1} = S_{i} + 2$ and $S_i > 0$. But both of these cases imply that $T_{i + k} = T_{i + k + 1}$, which is a contradiction, so $k$ cannot be even.

---

**Lemma (*):** For $u \in \{0, 1\}$ every vector, which in compressed form is written $u[1, 1, \dots, 1]$, is constructable with the above process. To proves this, consider first the case of $u = 0$. Then we can see that the vector $V = (1, -1, 1, -1, \dots)$ results in a vector $T = (0, 1, 0, 1, \dots)$. This is because the associated vector $S$ will be either $(0, 2, 0, 2, \dots)$ or $(-1, 1, -1, 1, \dots)$, depending on the parity of the length. For the case of $u = 1$, the vector $V = (-1, 1, -1, 1, \dots, -1, -1)$ or $V = (-1, 1, -1, 1, \dots, -1)$ will work. This is because the associated $S$ vector will be either $(2, 0, 2, 0, \dots)$ or $(1, -1, 1, -1, \dots)$, again depending on parity of length.

**Lemma (**):** All vectors in compressed form $C = u[c_1, c_2, \dots, c_m]$ are constructible with the above process whenever all $c_i$ are odd. We prove this by induction on $n$, the length of the original vector $V$. We start with two base cases $n = 1, 2$, so that we can jump by two in the inductive case. Well, we notice that both case we get that all $c_i$ being odd implies all $c_i = 1$, and so by **(*)** we are done.

For the inductive case, again if all $c_i = 1$, then we can just apply **(*)** and we're done. Else there is some $c_i \geq 3$. But then by induction the compressed form $u[c_1, c_2, \dots, c_i - 2, \dots, c_m]$ can be constructed. Now, look at the associated vector $T$ that results in this compressed form. The term $c_i - 2$ in the compressed vector corresponds to either $c_i - 2$ $0$s or that many $1s$ in a row. In either case, we can extend this to $c_i$ $0$s or $1$s by adding $(-1, 1)$ or $(1, -1)$ at the corresponding slot in the corresponding vector $V$. Doing this preserves the other $c_i$, and so we achieve our desired $C$.

**Corollary (lower bound):** A lower bound for $t_n$ is $2F_n$. That is $2F_n \leq t_n$. This is because the number of vectors of odd numbers adding up to $n$ is $F_n$ (as shown [elsewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1373878/ordered-sum-of-odd-numbers)), and the start term in the compressed form can be either $0$ or $1$.

---

Putting it all together, we have: $2F_n \leq t_n \leq 2F_{n + 2}$.

Comment: Well I got my answer for the sum of odd numbers in another post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1373878/ordered-sum-of-odd-numbers. It's the Fibonacci numbers. So my guess is the Fibonacci numbers are the key to the solution here.

Comment: Note: in particular I think for a vector of length $n$ the solution is $F_{n + 2}$, where $F_k$ is the $k^{th}$ Fibonacci number.

Comment: For $n=4$ I think the only possible values of $T$ are $(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1, 0), (1, 1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1, 0)$.

Comment: Ah I see. I think it's a little more complicated than I thought. I still think Fibonacci can be used somehow, and possibly different recurrence relations for even/odd length vectors.

Comment: If you see the new link I added to the question, it looks like you were right! All we need is a proof now :)

Comment: Exciting! I've been at a bit of a deadend these last few days, but still working on the problem. Since 2 days ago I've just made a few tiny steps. Suppose we extend the definition $S$ to a sequence of length $n + 1$ i.e. we let $j$ range from $0$ to $n$ in our definition of $S_j$. Then we know that $S_0$ = $-S_n$ for all vectors of length $n$. Also, I believe the following strategy might work for a proof: start with some vector $T$ satisfying the "odd subsequences" condition and try to find some $S$ that gives this $T$.

Comment: Or maybe try to find some $V$ that gives that $T$. Note that there is a many-to-one correspondence between vectors $V$ and $T$, because there are $2^n$ of the former, but less of the latter.

Comment: I've added a proof of the upper bound. Now we just need to chip away a bit more to get the exact value.

Comment: @phoenix: I think I may be on to something for a lower bound, or possibly even an exact value. Imagine an alternating sequence with the last element repeated: $(-1, 1, -1, 1, \dots, 1, 1)$ or $(1, -1, 1, -1, \dots, -1, -1)$. I think concatenating these together might allow us to build almost all sequences allowed by the upper bound, with the exception of the endpoints...

Comment: This is great! Sadly I can't upvote twice :)

Comment: Another idea. If we have a vector $T$ of length $n$ whose compressed form is $t_0[c_1, c_2, \dots, c_m]$ then we can have a vector of length $n + 2$ of the form $t_0[c_1, c_2, \dots, c_i + 2\dots, c_m]$. This is because, if $c_i$ is $0$ then we can add $(-1, 1)$ to the relevant slot in the original $V$ vector, leaving everything unchanged except lengthening the sequence of $0$s by $2$. Same for the case of  $c_i = 1$ except we add in $(1, -1)$. I think this could lead to an inductive proof of the value of $t_n$. It will at least give a lower bound (no doubt involving Fibonnaci numbers).

Comment: OK, I've added a lower bound. Now all that is left is to search for an exact value somewhere between $2F_n$ and $2F_{n + 2}$. What's really missing is a consideration of even start/end terms in the compressed form. When are these allowed? When are they not allowed?

Comment: I just realised I've misinterpreted the sums a little bit! In the question we always subtract a suffix from a non-empty prefix of the vector. Whereas I'm subtracting a non-empty suffix from a prefix. Not to worry, it's all symmetric, so the terms will work out the same :).

Comment: I think it's time to accept your answer. If you do work out how to get the exact answer suggested in the MO comments please do add it of course!

Comment: @phoenix unfortunately sometimes we must accept bounds. Though at least this one is tight enough. I would be very interested in seeing a full solution of this. I am just quite busy at the moment and don't have a lot of time to implement a proof strategy. Would it be possible for you to work on this yourself? I suggest considering different cases for the parity (even/odd) of the start/end terms of the compressed form, the parity of the length of the vector $n$, and the leading term in the compressed form. So $16$ cases altogether (I think), but you may be able to deal with some "chunks" at once

Comment: The answer given in SO seems to suggest that parity (even/odd) plays an important role. My intuition agrees with this- and I think checking various cases may uncover something along these lines. There is also the possibility of trying to find a recurrence between $t_n$ and $t_{n + 1}$ or even $t_{n + 2}$ and solving it, maybe using generating functions, though I'm no expert there. If I do have time, and if something hits me, I will definitely post it here.

Comment: @ColmBhandal: With respect to your question below according to *generating functions*. They are part of so-called formal methods and you might find *[this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/742083/book-on-combinatorial-identities/748850#748850)* helpful. P. Flajolet's and R. Sedgewick's *Analytic Combinatorics* is definitely a wonderful classic. But I think that Wilf's *[Generatingfunctionology](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfology2.pdf)* is the more easily accessible starter.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer- thanks! Will definitely check out that link. I actually started reading GeneratingFunctionology a few years ago but stopped because I didn't have time. I remember something about pegs on a clothes line... Also I am used to the term "formal methods" to refer to something quite different in computer science i.e. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_methods. I presume this is just a coincidence :)

Comment: @ColmBhandal: Oh, yes! It's more or less a *formal* coincidence. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Let $w=\sum_i v_i$ be the *weight* of $v$. The vector $S$ can be interpreted as a walk from $(0,-w)$ to $(n,w)$ with steps $(1,\pm2)$, in which the start point is not recorded.
The $T$ vector records whether the $y$ coordinate of the path is positive or not.

For example, the following figure illustrates the path for $v=(+---+++-++--+)$ whose $T$ vector is $1000001011101$, which we abbreviate as $1[1511311]$, recording the first term and the lengths of the runs.

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$ [image: example]

If a path strays above $4$ or below $-3$, then there's another path with the same $T$ vector that doesn't (as illustrated by the dotted line in the figure), so we can restrict our analysis to vectors whose weight is in the interval $[-3,4]$.

For each of these weights, the possible sequences of numbers in the abbreviated form of the $T$ vector are as follows. We use $\textsf{e}$ to denote an even number, $\textsf{o}$ to denote an odd number, and $(\textsf{oo})^\star$ to denote a sequence of zero or more pairs of odd numbers.
$$
\begin{array}{llll}
  w = \phantom{-}4 : & 0[\textsf{e}(\textsf{oo})^\star \textsf{e}] \\[3pt]
  w = \phantom{-}3 : & 0[\textsf{o}(\textsf{oo})^\star \textsf{e}] \\[3pt]
  w = \phantom{-}2 : & 0[\textsf{o}(\textsf{oo})^\star \textsf{o}] \\[3pt]
  w = \phantom{-}1 : & 0[\textsf{e}(\textsf{oo})^\star \textsf{o}] & \quad\text{or}\quad 1[\textsf{oo}(\textsf{oo})^\star \textsf{o}] & \quad\text{or}\quad 1[\textsf{o}] \\[3pt]
  w = \phantom{-}0 : & 1[\textsf{o}(\textsf{oo})^\star \textsf{o}] & \quad\text{or}\quad 0[\textsf{eo}(\textsf{oo})^\star \textsf{o}] & \quad\text{or}\quad 0[\textsf{e}] \\[3pt]
  w =           -1 : & 1[\textsf{e}(\textsf{oo})^\star \textsf{o}] & \quad\text{or}\quad 0[\textsf{oo}(\textsf{oo})^\star \textsf{o}] & \quad\text{or}\quad 0[\textsf{o}] \\[3pt]
  w =           -2 : & 1[\textsf{e}(\textsf{oo})^\star \textsf{e}] & \quad\text{or}\quad 0[\textsf{oo}(\textsf{oo})^\star \textsf{e}] & \quad\text{or}\quad 0[\textsf{e}] \\[3pt]
  w =           -3 : & 1[\textsf{o}(\textsf{oo})^\star \textsf{e}] 
\end{array}
$$
These sets of $T$ vectors are disjoint except for the two identical terms in the last column.

To enumerate, we use generating functions, remembering that the numbers in the abbreviated forms represent *runs* in the $T$ vectors.

Let $s(z)=1/(1-z)$ and $r(z)=zs(z)$ be the generating functions for possibly empty sequences and nonempty runs respectively. Then $e(z)=r(z^2)$ and 
$o(z)=zs(z^2)$ are the generating functions for nonempty even and odd length runs respectively.
The generating function for the number of distinct $T$ vectors is thus
$$
2r(z)^2s(o(z)^2) \:+\: 2r(z)o(z)^2s(o(z)^2) \:+\: r(z)+o(z)
\;=\;
\frac{2z+3z^2-z^4-2z^5-z^6}{1-4z^2+4z^4-z^6}
,
$$
where the first two summands come from the first and second columns in the table, noting that $e(z)+o(z)=r(z)$.

This generating function is the same as that ‘guessed’ by Jay Pantone on MathOverflow.

Extracting coefficients gives the number of distinct $T$ vectors of length $n$; one way of expressing this is
$$
t_n \;=\; \left\{
            \begin{array}{ll}
              4f_n  - 1, & n\;\text{even}, \\[3pt]
              2f_n + 4f_{n-1}, & n\;\text{odd},
            \end{array}
          \right.
$$
where $f_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number ($f_0=0$, $f_1=1$).

Comment: Nice work. Particularly kudos for working out all those cases. Looks good so far. Just trying to work through the generating functions part. I can't see exaclty how you get from the table to the generating functions. Admittedly, I know next to nothing about generating functions. Also, you mention "...possibly empty **sequences** and nonempty **runs** respectively". Are **sequencees** and **runs** different things?

Comment: @DavidBevan: Very nice and clever approach! I appreciate the restriction to the relevant path classes. (+1)

Comment: @ColmBhandal: I'd see the first chapter (only) of _Analytic Combinatorics_ by Flajolet & Sedgewick for a well written intro to the relevant stuff about generating functions. A PDF of the book is available online. Sequences and runs aren't really different, although in the context of this answer, you'll see that I've use them consistently to refer to different aspects of the argument. Btw, I've corrected a typo in the table.

Comment: @DavidBevan I presume by sequence you mean the whole T-vector and by run you mean just the segment of the same value repeated (0 or 1)? I'll check that link out if I have the time! I remember reading "generatingFunctionology" for a while but gave it up because I don't study that stuff officially. In the meantime, I trust your answer. It looks right. It also stays within the previously calculated bounds which is nice :)

Comment: @DavidBevan I know the *very basics* of generating functions i.e. more or less the formal definition. I'm just no whizz, so if you could add a few steps in the answer to dumb things down a bit for someone like me connecting the table to the generating functions I'd really appreciate it. Without much practice in this domain I'm finding it quite a struggle to retrace your logic. I'll also do some research myself and hopefully I'll meet you somewhere in the middle. Thanks :)

Comment: @DavidBevan the bounty period is up and you have answered the question, so fair is fair, the bounty goes to you.