# Number of words using $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ without "de" and "abd"

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

consider the words over the alphabet $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ of length $7$. What is the number of words that does not contain "de" and "abd" ?

A reasonable solution (I think) is to set $t_n$ to be the number of $n$-th long words without "de" and "abd",    and then to find a recurrence relation. From this recurrence we can compute $t_7$.

What is that recurrence relation? Is there another solution without recurrence? 
Thanks!

Comment: Do you know inclusion-exclusion method?

Comment: yes, but how to compute every sammand in P.I.E. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we use *[PIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)* the inclusion-exclusion principle to count the number of valid $7$-letter words from the alphabet $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ which do not contain the *bad* words $\{abd,de\}$.

> In order to do the job some kind of bookkeeping is helpful. We consider
>   \begin{align*}
> .\ .\ .\ .\ .\ .\ . &-\left(abd\ .\ .\ .\ .|de\ .\ .\ .\ .\ .\right)\tag{1}\\
> &+\left(abd\ abd\ .|abd\ de\ .\ .|abde\ .\ .\ .|de\ de\ .\ .\ .\right)\tag{2}\\
> &-\left(abde\ abd|abde\ de\ .|abd\, de\, de|de\ de\ de\ .\right)\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we count all $7$-letter words indicated by seven dots which gives $5^7$. Then we subtract all words which contain *at least* one bad word.

  Since $abd$ consumes three characters and four are left for free assignment, we count $\binom{5}{1}5^4$ words of this kind and similarly $\binom{6}{1}5^5$ in the other case with the bad word $de$.
- In (2) we add words containing two bad words as compensation for those which we've subtracted twice in (1), noting that we also have to consider *overlaps* $abd$ with $de$ giving $\color{blue}{abde}$.
- In (3) we finally subtract words containing three bad words which were added twice in (2). For instance $abde\ abd$ occurs in $\color{blue}{abd\ abd\ .}$ as well as in $\color{blue}{abde\ .\ .\ .}$
- No more cases are left to consider, since words containing four or more bad words have length $>7$.

> We obtain according to (1) to (3):
>   \begin{align*}
> 5^7&-\left(\binom{5}{1}5^4+\binom{6}{1}5^5\right)\\
> &\quad+\left(\binom{3}{2}5^1+2\binom{4}{2}5^2+\binom{4}{1}5^3+\binom{5}{2}5^3\right)\\
> &\quad-\left(2\binom{2}{2}5^0+2\binom{3}{2}5^1+\binom{3}{2}5^0+\binom{4}{3}5^1\right)\\
> &=78\,125-(3\,125+18\,750)+(15+300+500+1\,250)-(2+30+3+20)\\
> &=78\,125-21\,875+2\,065-55\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=58\,260}
> \end{align*}

**Note:** The *Goulden-Jackson Cluster* method used in another post is based upon the PIE approach and conveniently hides all this bookkeeping from us.

Answer (score 5):

The following answer is based upon the *[Goulden-Jackson Cluster Method](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9806036)*. We consider the set of words of length $n\geq 0$ built from an alphabet $$\mathcal{V}=\{a,b,c,d,e\}$$ and the set $B=\{abd,de\}$ of *bad words*, which are not allowed to be part of the words we are looking for. We derive a generating function $f(s)$ with the coefficient of $s^n$ being  the number of wanted words of length $n$.

According to the paper (p.7) the generating function $f(s)$  is
\begin{align*}
f(s)=\frac{1}{1-ds-\text{weight}(\mathcal{C})}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
with $d=|\mathcal{V}|=5$, the size of the alphabet and $\mathcal{C}$ is the *weight-numerator* of bad words with
\begin{align*}
\text{weight}(\mathcal{C})=\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[abd])+\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[de])\tag{2}
\end{align*}

> We calculate according to the paper
>   \begin{align*}
> \text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[abd])&=-s^3\\
> \text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[de])&=-s^2-s\cdot\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[abd])\tag{3}\\
> \end{align*}
>   so  that
>   \begin{align*}
> \text{weight}(\mathcal{C})=-s^3+\left(-s^2-s\cdot\left(-s^3\right)\right)=-s^2-s^3+s^4
> \end{align*}
>   The additional term on the right-hand side of (3) takes account of the overlapping of $ab\color{blue}{d}$ with $\color{blue}{d}e$.
>
> We obtain according to (1) and (3)
>   \begin{align*}
> f(s)&=\frac{1}{1-ds-\text{weight}(\mathcal{C})}\\
> &=\frac{1}{1-5s+s^2+s^3-s^4}\\
> &=1 + 5 s + 24 s^2 + 114 s^3 + 542 s^4 + 2577 s^5\\
> &\qquad + 12\,253 s^6 + \color{blue}{58\,260} s^7 + 277\,012 s^8 + 1\,317\,124 s^9 +\cdots
> \end{align*}
>   where the last line was calculated with the help of Wolfram Alpha.

**Result:** The blue marked coefficient of $s^{7}$  shows there are $\color{blue}{58\,260}$ words of length $7$ over the alphabet $\mathcal{V}$ which do not contain $abd$ or $de$.

Comment: May I know where did you study? Do you know some related books that are good for self learning? If you know a book with a simple English that would be fine because I am Arabic and my English is poor. You solved my problem before some months "words counting and ranking" amazingly, and you solved this problem amazingly, too.

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari: I've studied at the university of Vienna many years ago.  You might start with H. Wilf's *[Generatingfunctionology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/742083/book-on-combinatorial-identities/748850#748850)*. Please consult *[this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/742083/book-on-combinatorial-identities/748850#748850)* for more information.

Comment: Nice solution!  I would just like to point out that we don't really need Wolfram Alpha.  From the GF equation we have $(1-5s+s^2+s^3-s^4) f(s) = 1$ so if $f(s) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n s^n$ then $a_n - 5 a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}-a_{n-4}=0$ with $a_1=1$, so we have a recursion from which we can easily calculate $a_2,a_3,a_4$, etc.

Comment: @awkward: Yes, you're right of course, thanks. I use WA often as verification tool and typically, I also write additionally a code snippet, which generates the valid words (for small exponents). This way I can check the result with different approaches.

Comment: Just a correction to my previous comment, which I can't edit now: I should have written $a_0=1$, not $a_1=1$.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: This answer is incorrect; see comments below for discussion*

---

We can justify a recurrence as follows: as soon as there is a starting string that "fails to be" either `de` or `abd`, we can freely append any string that has no `de` nor `abd`.

We can fail produce a forbidden string in the following ways:

- Begin with b,c, or e. (3 ways, 1 slot used),
- Begin with d, followed by any letter besides e (4 ways, 2 slots used),
- Begin with a, followed by any letter besides b (4 ways, 2 slots used),
- Begin with ab, followed by any letter besides d (4 ways, 3 slots used).

This leads to the following recurrence:
$$
t_n = 3t_{n-1} + 8t_{n-2} + 4t_{n-3}; n \geq 3.
$$ 
The initial conditions are
$$
t_0 = 1, \quad t_1 = 5, \quad t_2 = 24.
$$

Comment: Thanks! I noticed that by your relation $t_3=116$. Should that note be $t_3=5^3-11=114$ (since we remove "abd" and "de$\star$", "$\star$de) ?

Comment: @boaz I agree with your observation, and honestly I'm not sure where I went wrong.  If setting $t_0 = 1$ is problematic then maybe the same recurrence using $t_1,t_2,t_3$ will give you the correct sequence, but I can't see why setting $t_0 = 1$ would lead to any issues here.

Comment: I think I see the problem: my recurrence is invalid since, for example, `ad` and `dd` cannot be freely followed by a valid string.

Comment: This is troubling; I really see no quick fix here.  Sorry about that.  I'll leave it up in case it's useful.